# Como rodar um video no Chrome do Android?

Tags: android, html, html5, google-chrome, vídeo

Como executar um video com a tag video no browser google Chrome?

Meu código:

```
<video autobuffer id="bgVideo" loop="true" volume="0">
                    <source src="/video_bg_1.webm" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="/video_bg_1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    <source src="/video_bg_1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remova o atributo `type` da tag `source` e implemente o play via JavaScript.

```
var player = document.getElementById("bgVideo");

function playVideo() {
  player.play();
}
```

coloque esta função em `body onload = "playVideo()"`
e na tag video coloque o atributo `loop`  para ficar repetindo o video.
talvez isso resolva.

Comment: é que estou usando esse video como background